# How to implement OAuth wrapper for Laravel 4

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, laravel-4

I wish to make use of [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) to integrate facebook login facilities but I have problems implementing the package.

Everything on the installation guide on [github](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) is clear, my challenge comes at the level of making the `::get()` and `::post` request.

I do not event know how it should look like. Please can some one walk me through with a live demo? I do appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution after a long time of struggle.My

```
::post();
```

and

```
::get();
```

request points to the same function as specified in the doc at github
for example:

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'AuthController@loginWithFacebook');
Route::post('login/facebook', 'AuthController@loginWithFacebook');
```

It is clearer now.